# Перетасовка элементов

Tags: python, list, случайные-числа

Каким образом можно случайно переставить все элементы в списка?
То есть, к примеру, я хочу перетасовать список [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], чтобы на выходе получить список с этими же элементами, но на случайных позициях.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/976918/10138734

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1

```
import random 
random.shuffle(array)
```

Вариант 2

```
B = sorted([1,2,3,4], key=lambda A: random.random())
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import random

y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
random.shuffle(y)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь модулем random

```
import random

numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
random.shuffle(numbers)
```